# PHP how to send a pdf attachment without it being corrupted

Tags: php, pdf, phpmailer

I am having some trouble with a simple function to send a pdf file - the email sends but the attachment is corrupted when I try to open it, so obviously my function is doing something wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {

$file = $path.$filename;

$file_size = filesize($file);

$handle = fopen($file, "r");

$content = fread($handle, $file_size);

fclose($handle);

$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";

$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";

$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";

$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"attachment.pdf\"\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";

$header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";

$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; 

$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";

$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";

$header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";

$header .= "--".$uid."--";






wp_mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header);


}
```

Comment: don't build your own mime emails. use a proper mail package like phpmailer and swiftmailer. that'll reduce pretty much ALL of that code to a single `$mail->AddAttachment(...)`-type call. and since you've tagged this question with phpmailer - why aren't you using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your e-mail headers are off quite a bit.  A proper multipart message would look something like this:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="_----------=_1458761739257530"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: xxxxx
From: xxxxx
To: xxxxx
Reply-To: xxxx
Subject: xxxx

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--_----------=_1458761739257530
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain

This is the plain-text part of my message
That's all.

--_----------=_1458761739257530
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="myfile.pdf"

<base64 content here>

--_----------=_1458761739257530--
```

But really, you shouldn't be generating headers like that one your own - there are lots of ways to mess it up.  Instead, use any number of the existing PHP libraries that will generate the MIME headers, do the encoding, and handle the mailing for you.

For example, your distribution very likely includes the PEAR modules "Mail" and "Mail_Mime", or else you can install them easily with `pear install Mail Mail_Mime`

Then do something like:

```
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {

    require_once('Mail.php');
    require_once('Mail/mime.php');

    $file = $path.$filename;

    $headers = array (
      'From'     => $from_mail,
      'To'       => $mailto,
      'Reply-To' => $replyto,
      'Subject'  => $subject,
    );

    $mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => "\n"));

    $mime->SetTXTBody($message);
    $mime->addAttachment($file, 'application/octet-stream');

    $mime_body    = $mime->get();
    $mime_headers = $mime->headers($headers);

    $mail =& Mail::factory('mail');
    $mail->send($mailto, $mime_headers, $mime_body);

     if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
      echo("<p>ERROR:" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>\n");
    } else {
      echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>\n");
    }
}
```